# Append text to NSScrollView - Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsscrollview, nsviewcontroller, nspopover

I am doing a Mac application, and I have a problem appending text to a NSScrollView when I call a function from a different class.

I have this function on my ViewController class:

```
import Cocoa

class PopoverVC1: NSViewController {

let popover1 = NSPopover()

class func loadView() ->PopoverVC1 {
    let vc = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), 
bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: 
NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "Popover1")) as! PopoverVC1
    vc.popover1.contentViewController = vc
    return vc
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    popover1.behavior = .transient
    popover1.contentViewController = self
}

func showPopover (view: NSView){
popover1.show(relativeTo: view.bounds, of: view, preferredEdge: .maxY)

}

@IBOutlet weak var radioOption1: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var radioOption2: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var radioOption3: NSButton!


@IBAction func clickOption(_ sender: NSButton) {
    switch sender {
    case radioOption1: popover1.performClose(sender)

    case radioOption2: let vc = ViewController()
        vc.myPrint(string: "This is a test")

    default: print ("hello")

    }
}
}
```

Than I have a PopoverVC1 class, which is a class to a popover I am using:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var oneYes: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var oneNo: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var notesArea: NSScrollView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded
    }
}

func myPrint (string: String){
    let mystring = string
    let myNotes = notesArea.documentView as? NSTextView
    let text = myNotes?.textStorage!
    let attr = NSAttributedString(string: mystring)
    text?.append(attr)

}

let popover1 = NSPopover()
@IBAction func oneClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {


    switch sender {
    case oneYes: let vc = PopoverVC1.loadView()
        vc.showPopover(view: sender)

    case oneNo:
    let myNotes = notesArea.documentView as? NSTextView
    let text = myNotes?.textStorage!
    let attr = NSAttributedString(string: "test")
    text?.append(attr)

    default: print ("")
    }
}
}
```

However, I got an error when I press the radio button "oneNo" that should call the function "myPrint" and pass the argument.

**Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

I did some tests and when I call this same function "myPrint" from within the ViewCotroller class it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is vc and notesArea created?

Comment: `notesArea` must be nil when you use it.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, could you give me an example? I'm new to swift :(

Comment: `@IBOutlet` property must be linked with a appropriate view object from `xib` or `storyboard` files. If not it will be crashed.

Comment: @AllenR, the notes area is in my ViewController. I have a ViewCotroller for my storyboard window, and I have a Popover. I want to press a radiobutton in my popover and add a text to my notesArea

Comment: I ask because it seems like `notesArea` is not initialized at the time you are calling `myPrint`. I don't think the problem is with calling `myPrint` from your popover. If you can show more code for your `vc` then we could be of more help.

Comment: @AllenR, you are right because if I modify the myPrint function to something like: func myPrint(){ print ("test")} it works. But you can see that I have another functions - oneClicked, in my ViewController, and that works fine. The functions are similar. My problem is to pass an argument from my popover.

Comment: @AllenR, I added more code to my question.

Comment: Can you also show the popover class code? For some reason `notesArea` is not initialized when you are calling the `myPrint` function from the popover class. That is way it is saying its `nil`.

Comment: @AllenR, it's all there.

Comment: Your problem is that you create a new `ViewController` instance and you then call a method (`didPrint`) on that new view controller instance. That method in turn tries to access the `notesArea` property but the outlet hasn't been setup yet. Hence the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy, and how do I solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in `clickOption` when you are calling:

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.myPrint(string: "This is a test")
```

When you call this method from code and the `ViewController's` `UIViews` are set up in a storyboard, the connection from the storyboard is not made. That is why the `notesArea` is nil when you call the function `myPrint`. In this case you are creating a new copy of `ViewController` and it will not be the same one that created the popover.

There are a few ways you can solve the problem that you are trying to accomplish. One of them is known as a `delegate`. This is a way for you to to call the `ViewController's` methods like your `popover` inherited them. You can check out a tutorial [here](https://medium.com/a-swift-misadventure/introducing-swift-action-delegate-pattern-c2e6a7d4880). The idea is that we want to have a reference to the `ViewController` in your `popover` so that you can call the functions in the `protocol`. Then the `ViewController` that conforms to the `protocol` will be responsible for handling the method call.

So let's create a `protocol` called `PrintableDelegate` and have your `ViewController` class conform to it. Then in your `popover`, you will be able to have a reference to the `ViewController` as a `weak var` called `delegate` (you can use what ever name you want but `delegate` is standard). Then we can call the methods described in the protocol `PrintableDelegate`, by simply writing `delegate?.myPrint(string: "Test")`. I have removed some of your irrelevant code from my example.

```
protocol PrintableDelegate {
    func myPrint(string: String)
}

class ViewController : UIViewController, PrintableDelegate {

    func myPrint (string: String){
        let mystring = string
        let myNotes = notesArea.documentView as? NSTextView
        let text = myNotes?.textStorage!
        let attr = NSAttributedString(string: mystring)
        text?.append(attr)
    }

    @IBAction func oneClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
        let vc = PopoverVC1.loadView()
        // Set the delegate of the popover to this ViewController
        vc.delegate = self
        vc.showPopover(view: sender)
    }
}

class PopoverVC1: NSViewController {

    // Delegates should be weak to avoid a retain cycle
    weak var delegate: PrintableDelegate?

    @IBAction func clickOption(_ sender: NSButton) {
        // Use the delegate that was set by the ViewController
        // Note that it is optional so if it was not set, then this will do nothing
        delegate?.myPrint(string: "This is a test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Brillant Allen! After 3 days looking for a solution, it finally worked! Thanks a lot. And also, thank you for the explanation!